# IntelliJ IDEA: P4 status takes forever to refresh

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control, perforce, intellij-14

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.1;
my project uses Perforce as a VCS.

The JetBrains-provided integration was working fine until today.
Now, it's not usable any longer: the status is outdated (shows changelists I've submitted hours ago as "pending"), and both "Refresh" and "Force Refresh" operations take forever to complete:

[image: IDEA Version Control]

My working copy is fine: I can work with it using either P4 command line utility or P4V.

The problem is not memory and/or OS-related: I've restarted my PC, and the problem still persists. So the question is: which exact file under `${PROJECT_ROOT}/.idea` do I need to edit/unlink in order for the issue to go away?

**Update:** [File | Invalidate Caches/Restart](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/cleaning-system-cache.html) isn't helpful, either.

Comment: Hard to tell. Please create an issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newissue and attach your log there (Help | Show log)